# Add variable in gradle command

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing

I have to following gradle code:

```
testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    unitTests.all {
        // All the usual Gradle options.
        jvmArgs '-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m'
    }

    execution 'ANDROID_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR'
}
```

And I am using Android test orchestrator, but I makes my UI tests take a lot of time to run. So I would like to be able to request for orchestrator in the command line like:

```
./gradlew androidConnectedCheck --orchestrator
```

So I can controll when to use orchestator.  **Is it possible to do that with gradle?**

Edit:

I am not interested in using a gradle variable in my code (in Java or Kotlin) I would like to create a conditional test configuration accordingly with my command line

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't see as duplicated. I don't wanna use the Gradle variable in Java. I would like to create a conditional test type accordingly with my shell command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./gradlew androidConnectedCheck -Porchestrator
```

And in gradle, you can do:

```
def orchestrator = project.hasProperty('orchestrator')
```

`orchestrator` will be true if it was passed as an arg. This uses the [project-prop](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_properties_and_system_properties) built into gradle command line.